# be agreed to/with/by

Tags: meaning

> 1 This action was agreed with Jake.
>
> 2 This action was agreed to with Jake.
>
> 3 This action was agreed to by Jake.

There are difference opinions on the correctness of the three.

Do you agree that 2 is wrong while 1 and 3 are correct?

Comment: Try rewriting each as an active sentence (you could edit this into the question)  This might indicate difference between the sentence that aren't clear in the passive forms.

Comment: They're all perfectly grammatical - as would be #4 *This action was agreed **by** Jake*, if we assume OP is  just checking all permutations of **to** or nothing followed by ***with*** or ***by***, which is what it looks like to me). It's semantically irrelevant whether ***to*** is present or not. The difference is ***with** Jake* implies the speaker *interacted* with Jake to get that agreement (effectively, the speaker *also* agreed with the action)....

Comment: ...but ***by** Jake* just means Jake agreed to the action - but the speaker may not have interacted with Jake to get that agreement. In fact, the speaker might simply be reporting an agreement that he wasn't involved in at all.